# JQuery syntax - remove() won't work on element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to remove a particular element within a container if it exists.  The below code alerts to tell me the element exists but for whatever reason, does not remove and oes not provide any error messages.

```
var second_page_item = $('DIV#discount_0 > .element .first_static .second_page .isotope-item');
if($(second_page_item).length == 0) {
    alert('it here');
    $(second_page_item).remove(); //WHY DOESNT IT REMOVE?
}
```

Comment: If length is equal to zero, what do you want to remove?

Comment: how can that alert be shown??

Comment: Did you focus on your code? Just look at this again

Comment: @giammin - the alert is shown if the selector has no length, i.e. the element doesn't exist

Comment: I've just realised the alert shows regardless so I suppose the way I am checking if the element exists is wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`second_page_item` is already a jQuery object, so there's no reason to run jQuery on it again. Also, a `length` of 0 would mean it doesn't exist. This is a more logical approach to your version of the code.

```
var second_page_item = $('DIV#discount_0 > .element .first_static .second_page .isotope-item');
if ( second_page_item.length > 0 ) {
  second_page_item.length.remove();
}
```

However, you can simply do.

```
$('DIV#discount_0 > .element .first_static .second_page .isotope-item').remove();
```

Answer (score 3):

So if it ....

```
if($(second_page_item).length == 0) {
```

.... has no length, and doesn't exist, remove it

```
$(second_page_item).remove();
```

makes perfect sense, but there's nothing to remove ?

Answer (score 0):

It should work:

```
if($(second_page_item).length > 0) {
    alert('it here');
    $(second_page_item).remove();
}
```